# iOS Design - Is back button mandatory

Tags: ios

The dashboard screen displays a menu icon on the left, clicking on which the slide menu is displayed on the left too. Now when the user goes from the dashboard screen to another screen, say profile screen, on the top left we display the menu icon. To go back to the previous menu, the user needs to click on the menu and select the option, "Go To Dashboard".

My query is that, is this as per the iOS design guideline and it is mandatory to display back button on 2nd level screens for easier navigation. Actually, we need to display the menu icon always in the 2nd level windows too.

Comment: I removed the Appcelerator tag as this is iOS generic. I also voted for close as this is completely off topic on Stackoverflow.

Comment: But as a short answer, if you don't add a back button, how else is the user supposed to get back to the previous screen?

Comment: @RenePot, I have mentioned in the question that you can go back by selecting the "Go To Dashboard" from the slide menu. The menu icon will be displayed in the left where the back button is displayed.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously it is totally legal to suppress the Back button. If it were not, why would there be a settable [`hidesBackButton`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uinavigationitem/1624947-hidesbackbutton) property?

Answer (score 1):

Back button is automatically generated if you use navigation controller. But, you are free to customize it. I did same thing and launched my app in App Store last year. It hasn't caused any bugs so far.